# JToken DateTime returning wrong string format

Tags: c#, json, rest, attask, workfront-api

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
JToken myToken = client.Search(ObjCode.BASELINE, new {fields="entryDate"});
console.WriteLine(myToken);
```

This returns the following:

```
{"data": [ {"entryDate": "2015-02-20T11:11:40:706-0500"} ] }
```

My problem is that whenever I try to assign the value of the field I get an error saying that the string format for the dateTime returned is not correct. I've tried `DateTime.Parse`, `DateTime.ParseExact` and none of these work. From what I can tell the DateTime string is supposed to be something like `"2015-02-20T11:11:40.706-0500"` where there is a period NOT a colon after the time on the string. 
Am I right on saying REST is returning the wrong format or is there a way to cast the given format to the correct DateTime format?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how you generated that JSON string using Json.NET, since Json.NET itself cannot parse `"entryDate"` into a `DateTime`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/jyofkk.  Perhaps it's actually just a string literal stored in whatever system you searched?

Comment: If you replace the colon I was talking about previously with a period instead, right before 706, the code will run without any errors.

Comment: You can check the expected data types from the API using the /metadata action, in this case `/BLIN/metadata/` which does state that **entryDate** is a `"dateTime"` field type. If it doesn't parse out correctly it might very well be that the serialization is incorrect. You could parse using something along the lines of `DateTime.ParseExact(entryDate, "yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:ss:ffffff")`

Answer (score 0):

EntryDate is an Audit Field and cannot be set: the underlying Oracle Database has a trigger on it that supplies the current time On Insert. I suspect the messages you are getting are trying to report that, but losing something in translation. I suggest you firm up your syntax on a writeable field such as Planned Date. Once that works, try EntryDate again.

Regards,
Doug